# Node.js multiple express objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, global, router

I have been trying to understand how Expressjs framework for Node.js handles routes in multiple files with no luck. My main index.js looks similar  this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/route', require('./api/route'));
app.set('important_var', global_var);
```

In the last line I set one global variable for my application, which is needed by all other routes.

In the second JS file './api/route.js', I do kinda the same thing:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = app.Router(); 
router.get('/path1', () => {...});
```

In the second file I need an important_var which was set on application level in index.js. How can I access it? Am I allowed to create new (if it is considered new) object with express()? Is variable app from index.js considered as singleton and won't be recreated? How should I handle these kind of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then these are the requirements you are trying to meet:

- A main file that configures the server.
- The main file sets "global" values that can be accessed by various routes within the application.
- A sub router file that can access the global values.

If those requirements are correct then the following is a way of meeting them the Express way.

Using [`app.set`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set) for storing app globals can lead to issues since it is for assigning an app setting value. Instead, app globals can safely be stored to a [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.locals) which is specifically intended for this use case.

So in your main file (`/index.js`):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const subRouter = require('./api/route');

app.locals.important_var = 'My App Global';

app.use('/route', subRouter);
```

Then to access the app global in your sub router file (`/api/route.js`) you would use the [`req.app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.app) object which is a reference back to `app.locals`:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = router;

router.get('/path1', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.app.locals.important_var);
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I was thinking about using that `important_var` in the global scope of the router file. I understand it works in the router.get/post/put/... callback functions. But is there a way of accessing global variable from outside that scope?

Comment: @SrdjanRistanovic That wouldn't be an Express app global but rather a node [global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) which is an anti-pattern in general for JavaScript. One alternative for using constants in various files would be using a module that acts as a constants object. It can be a plain JSON file: `const config = require('./constants');` OR explicitly as `const constants = require('./constants.json');` and node will automatically parse it for you.

Answer (score 0):

To access values set with `app.set()`, you need to be able to call `app.get()` and it needs to be the same `app` object that you used when you called `app.set()`.  Each `app` is an Express object and it keeps its own state.

When create route handlers using a router, you can access the `app` object that a given route is associated with via `req.app`.  So, if you have code in a router you can access things on the `app` object like this:

```
router.get('/path1', () => {
    let data = req.app.get('important_var');
    // rest of route handler here
});
```

---

It may be more common to use middleware and set a property of your own on the `req` object that all route handlers could then access:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// custom middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.myImportantVar = someCalculation(important_var);
    next();
});

app.use('/route', require('./api/route'));
```

Then, in a router, you could do this:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/path1', () => {
     console.log(req.myImportantVar);
     // rest of route handler here
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `req.set` as it can conflict with server settings. As noted in my answer it is much safer and the intended use case to use `app.locals` which is referenced via the request object by `req.app.locals`. It should also be considered an anti-pattern to modify the request object directly as it can conflict with existing properties. If a request specific variable needs to be stored between middleware, that is what the `req.locals` object is for. Further, setting a constant value on every request is an unnecessary step as you can set an app variable once on startup.

Comment: @JasonCust - Either can work.  `app.locals` is a fine solution too.  The Express doc for `app.set()` says: "You may store any value that you want".  Of course, you need to not create a naming conflict.  I just preface my symbols with `_` and no conflict.  The OP asked about `app.set()` and `app.get()` so I answered for them how to use that.

Comment: The same comment I wrote in the other answer. Can I somehow access it in the global scope, meaning outside the callback function for router methods?

Comment: @SrdjanRistanovic - Yes, if you share the `app` object into the module, then you can call `app.get()` anywhere in the module or you can share the variable directly.   You can pass it into the module when you load it by creating a module constructor function where you do your initialization.  This is the same way you share any variables from a parent module into a module the parent is loading.